# what is jquery noConflict, why do we need that?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have seen a jquery code that contains jQuery.noConflict method.

do not know purpose of it, didnt get the why we need that.

i only understand that it is something related to jquery plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery (and other frameworks like it) store an alias of the jQuery object in the `$` variable.  It's just for easy shorthand when you write code.

You could actually write all your code like this `jQuery('.selector');` instead of using the dollar sign if you wanted to.  The no-conflict mode allows you to use other code (usually another framework) that ALSO stores something in the dollar sign variable.

Comment: confused. but how they identify which $ is this

Comment: When you use noConflict, you release the jQuery alias from the dollar sign.  So, for the rest of your code, you can only use this syntax: `jQuery('.whatever');` for jQuery actions, and you can use the dollar sign for the other framework.

Answer (score 10):

It is especially useful when there are more than one javascript libraries used on a page like jQuery, prototype, etc. The `$` character is special in those libraries as in jQuery. For this reason, `jQuery.noConflict`.

See:

[Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) (Official Docs)

**Update:**

Once you have used `jQuery.noConflict`, the control of `$` is handed over to other libraries rather than jQuery and in this case, you will have to use `jQuery` rather than `$`.

Other alternative that turns out to be especially useful when writing jQuery plugins is something like:

```
(function($){
 // your code....
})(jQuery);
```

In this case though, you can use the `$` normally even if other libraries are included on the page.

Comment: ok, can you explain me in a simple way how it works, and its usage

Comment: @cache: See the link in my answer.

Comment: confused. but how they identify which $ is this