# Use of $ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know what is the use of $ in jQuery. But i want to know what is the behavior of $ in the below context.

```
        var Page = {
       
        init: function () {

            **Page.element = $("content");**
         }
        }
```

I understand you might say that this reference is to an element name content. But NO! I actually have a DIV tag here with an

**id="content"**

and this works perfectly fine for it..

And the funny thing is if i add a reference to jquery as below it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

i tried with several versions of jquery

---

here is the entire javascript on the page

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  
    var Page = {

        init: function () {

            Page.element = $("content");
           
            Page.photo = $("body-photo");
            Page.points = $("body-points");
            Page.panel = $("content-2");
            
            Page.content = $("content-1");
            Page.contentCloseBtn = $$("#content-1 .close-btn")[0];

            Page.zoomOutBtn = $$("#content-2 .zoom-out-btn")[0];

                      
            Page.contentCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", bind(function () {
                var state = hasClass(Page.content, "open");
                if (state) removeClass(Page.content, "open")
                else addClass(Page.content, "open")
            }, Page), false);


            Page.attach();
            
        },

        attach: function () {
            Page.points.addEventListener("click", function () { Page.zoomIn.call(); alert('ccc'); }, false);
        },

        zoomIn: function () {
            Page.points.removeEventListener("click", Page.boundZoomIn, false);
            Page.photo.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", Page.zoomInEnd, false);

            addClass(Page.element, "zoom-in");

        },

        zoomInEnd: function () {
            Page.photo.removeEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", Page.zoomInEnd, false);
            Page.zoomOutBtn.addEventListener("click", Page.zoomOut, false);

            addClass(Page.element, "zoom-in-end");
            addClass(Page.panel, "expanded");
        },

        zoomOut: function () {
            Page.zoomOutBtn.removeEventListener("click", Page.zoomOut, false);

            removeClass(Page.panel, "expanded")
            removeClass(Page.element, "zoom-in-end");
            removeClass(Page.element, "zoom-in");
        }
    };
    
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", bind(Page.init, Page), false);
    function startAnimation() {
        Page.init.call(Page);
    }
   
     startAnimation();

    
</script>
```

I want it to be working with the reference to jquery coz this file is being imported into another webpage which has and requires jquery reference

Here is the HTML

```
<body class="slide-7">
<div id="content" >
    <header>
        <h1>xxxx</h1>
        <h2>xxxx.</h2>
    </header>
    
    <div id="body-photo">
        <img src="xxxx.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
        <ul id="body-points" class="hotspot-list">
            <li class="hotspot-1"></li>
            <li class="hotspot-2">
                <div class="tooltip">
                   xxxx
                    <div class="tooltip-corner"></div>
                </div>                
            </li>
            <li class="hotspot-3"></li>
            <li class="hotspot-4"></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>


    <section id="content-1">
        <article>
            <header>xxxx.</header>       
            <p>xxxx.</p>
            <p>xxxx.</p>
        </article>
        <div class="close-btn"></div>
    </section>


    <section id="content-2">
        <article>
            <figure><img src="xxxx.jpg" alt="" /></figure>                
            <hgroup>
                <h1>xxxx</h1>
                <h2>xxxx.</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <div class="copy">
                xxxx            
            </div>

        </article>
        <div class="article-icons">
            <img class="active zoom-out-btn" src="xxxx.png" alt="" />
            <img src="xxxx.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="maximize-btn"></div> -->
    </section>


    


</div>
</body>
```

Any links related to this senario would also be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You most definitely have included a script that uses $ to select element by it's id.

Comment: @Zenith In the convention that *jQuery* happens to use...!

Comment: according to jquery convention id selector should have # ... but here it doesnt and if i add a reference to jquery than this code doesnt work as i mention in the question...

Comment: Yes, because `$` will then refer to `jQuery` and not to whatever it referred to before (a function which seems to be calling `document.getElementById`).

Comment: `$('#...')` is not the only way to select an element by id, and if another library decides `$('...')` should do it then it can. And does.

Comment: alright... i'l check the other libraries which i have imported and see if it works... thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, that snippet is built upon [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/). It's another JavaScript library like jQuery and it also uses `$` as a shorthand, but it works differently.

In Prototype, [`$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) selects using an ID whereas [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) selects using a CSS selector. jQuery on the other hand only exports the `$` shorthand to select using a CSS selector, which differs from the usage in Prototype. By including jQuery as well (without `noConflict` mode), the `$` calls break since they're now handled by jQuery instead.

Comment: \* Probably. But likely.

Comment: Yeah.. there was the prototype library... i removed the conflict by making the prototype library use another symbol instead of $... That was Simple!   thankx :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$` symbol doesn't have any special meaning in pure Javascript. In fact that is the reason that jQuery is able to use it and create the *jQuery function* which is aliased to the `$` symbol.

So your script does the same thing. The good news is that jQuery allows you to operate in what they call "no conflict mode". See this other question: [What is jquery noconflict, why do we need that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230941/what-is-jquery-noconflict-why-do-we-need-that)

That said, you'd probably be better off rewriting the smaller script to use jQuery instead. It looks like it's a pretty simple script and there won't be a lot to change. And you could benefit from the exercise..

Comment: we can use our own alias for jQuery right?

Comment: yes, you can create your own alias.